# beginSheetModalForWindow

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, alert

What's wrong with this piece of code, copied/pasted from Apple's examples? The alert appears very shortly over the window and then the application terminates (without any error).

```
    (NSApplicationTerminateReply)applicationShouldTerminate:(NSNotification *)notification {
     return NSTerminateCancel;
     if (registerModified){
     NSAlert *testAlert = [NSAlert alertWithMessageText:@"Voulez-vous enregister les modifications du registre?"
     defaultButton:@"Enregistrer"
     alternateButton:@"Ne pas enregistrer"
     otherButton:nil
     informativeTextWithFormat:@"Ces modifications seront permanentes."];

    [testAlert beginSheetModalForWindow:[self mainWindow]
     modalDelegate:self
     didEndSelector:@selector(alertDidEnd:returnCode:contextInfo:)
     contextInfo:nil];
    }


    - (void)alertDidEnd:(NSAlert *)alert returnCode:(NSInteger)returnCode contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
    {
    #pragma unused (contextInfo)
    [[alert window] orderOut:self];
    }
```

beginSheetModalForWindow… if you are very fast!

Comment: You sure the sheet does appear? The code you posted does not show any sheet at all.

Comment: The code you posted can't show a sheet because you have a return statement as the first line, so nothing after that will be executed.  I moved that statement to after the if clause, and it ran fine (meaning it showed the sheet and didn't terminate).